# Why does the .Rd file not contain a link to another function when I \code{\link{functionname}}?

Tags: r, roxygen2, package-development

I am using `package::roxygen2` to develop a package with RStudio. Below is are the roxygen comments to one of my functions, called `coltrain()`.

```
#' Collect raw training data using external SQL queries.
#'  
#'  @details This is a wrapper for the \code{get_data} function.
#'  It runs all of the queries tagged as training data queries.
#'  
#'  @seealso \code{\link{get_data}}
```

The function `get_data()` is also in my package, and I have already run `load_all(".")` and `document()`. Yet there is no hyperlink to the `get_data` help file in the `coltrain` help file.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try using `\code{\link[YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME]{get_data}}` I don't think you're supposed to have to do this explicitly for within your own package.

Comment: Tried that and still no go.

Comment: Is this package on GitHub by chance?

Comment: No, it is on BitBucket, and it is a private package with proprietary stuff in it. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to properly build and install the package before links are present. `load_all()` will not be enough to create the proper linking...